# Azure Private Network Gateway - removing propagated network

Tags: azure, vpn

I have created Azure Virtual Network with address space 10.50.50.0/23, in it, I have created 5 subnets - 10.50.50.0/26, 10.50.50.64/26, 10.50.50.128/26, 10.50.51.0/26 and 172.16.0.0/26, on top of this network I have created Virtual Network Gateway (VPN) with point to site 10.99.99.0/25, I would like to limit routing only to 2 subnets 10.50.51.0/26 and 10.50.51.64/26 - for doing that I've added --custom-routes for only those two network ... but still in my client I've saw routing to whole network range (10.50.50.0/23), same after creating new route table and creating new hop's ... any idea how to modify that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirmed with Microsoft, currently not supported.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to limit the route on the client, you should add a route on the client instead of the Azure virtual network. In fact, you can find the route of the VPN client in the file `VpnSettings.xml` of the folder **Generic** from [VPN client downloaded folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/point-to-site-vpn-client-configuration-azure-cert#generate).

The file `VpnSettings.xml` will like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<VpnProfile xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <VpnServer>azuregateway-xxxxx-xxx.vpn.azure.com</VpnServer>
  <VpnType>SSTP</VpnType>
  <CaCert>xxxxx</CaCert>
  <Routes>10.0.0.0/16</Routes>
  <Auth>EAPTLS</Auth>
  <VnetName>example-network</VnetName>
  <VnetId>06e10077-xxxx-xxxx-84d6-5aa4db8b6752</VnetId>
  <ServerCertRootCn>DigiCert Global Root CA</ServerCertRootCn>
  <ServerCertIssuerCn>DigiCert Global Root CA</ServerCertIssuerCn>
  <VpnClientAddressPool>192.168.100.0/24</VpnClientAddressPool>
  <AadIssuer />
  <AadTenant />
  <AadAudience />
  <CustomDnsServers />
</VpnProfile>
```

You could try to modify the route to `<Routes>10.50.51.0/26,10.50.51.64/26</Routes>` then you could reinstall the VPN client package like `VpnClientSetupAmd64.exe`.

In addition, you can use an Azure [network security group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/network-security-groups-overview) to filter network traffic `to` and `from` Azure resources in an Azure virtual network.

Comment: as far as I'm aware NSG won't work on VPN gateway, I have also changed the values in <Routes> - but those are being refreshed after I connect to gateway this new route is coming from VPN "propagated routes"

Comment: You could use NSG rules to limit client address rang to allow access some subnets but deny access some subnets.